# Поиск подключённых в режиме реального времени

Tags: python, tornado

Всем привет! Есть у меня сокет-сервер на Python. Он держит в памяти массив подключённых в данное время к нему пользователей с их данными(возраст допустим). Где в такой системе делать бесконечный цикл ищущщий одинаковых людей по возрасту? Паралельный поток какой-то может сделать?

В таком случаи  получается запуск этого сервера на питоне - это открытие порта для приёма веб сокетов, запуск бесконечного цикла в паралельном потоке. Будет ли этот бесконечный цикл в паралельном потоке работать с актуальным массивом подключённых пользователей к сокету? Посоветуйте, как сделать правильнее такой поиск среди подключённых людей?

Comment: А зачем бесконечно искать одинаковых по возрасту. Нашли один раз, массив закончился, что дальше то искать, до подключения следующего

Comment: А как вы предлагаете это делать только при подключении? Допустим двое подключились - что теперь гонять два раза тот же цикл? Я посчитал правильным сделать так: крутить while(true) а в нём цикл на поиск похожих людей в массиве, который изменяется другими процессами. Если есть предложения как этот цикл запускать/останавливать (при этом проверять не запущен ли он уже другим пользователем) - наппишите, пожалуйста, фреймворк tornado. Делаю через IOLoop.instance().add_callback

Comment: не понятно зачем вообще циклы. строите хеш массивов или списков по годам рождения.

Comment: Ну хеш это ладно, не суть, механизм непосредственно поиска людей не трогаем. А бесконечный цикл вот для чего. Допустим всё это работает без бесконечного цикла. Два подходящих друг дургу людей подключились, если у нас нету одного бесконечного цикла, обрабатывающего подключенных людей, то подключённый человек запустит механизм проверки подходящих ему людей, так ещё и тот кого он ищет тоже этот механизм запустит. Итого: будет 2 оповещения о том, что человек найден, будет дубляж. Так что за это должен отвечать один механизм. Опишите пожалуйста как вы это видите

Comment: А бесконечный цикл будет бесконечно находить совпадающих людей и будет бесконечный дубляж. Вам в любом случае запоминать о ком уже сообщали. Да и какой собственно дубляж. Если у вас многопоточное приложение, то начало поиска берет блокировку, что бы одновременно работало только в 1 потоке. ищет всех, кто есть на данный момент, сообщает о них, снимает блокировку. Второй процесс начинает искать - всех подходящих и сообщает им только о себе. А его в списке еще не было, пока первый искал

Comment: Ясное дело при нахождении он обоих из массива удаляет. А как эту блокировку сделать?

Comment: А вы действительно используете потоки ? Если да, то как вы это делаете ничего не зная о блокировках. Это как бы базовый механизм без которого в принципе работа многопоточного приложения не возможна (ну если потоки между собой общаются). Вы же без блокировки ни одной общей переменной менять не можете, не говоря уже об общем списке пользователей, который вроде как ведете... посмотрите базовую документацию на работу потоков в вашем языке. там должен быть раздел что то типа "средства cинхронизации"

Comment: До этого не использовал потоки, а сейчас нужен поиск, поэтому и нужно вынести в другой поток. Но не знаю как это правильно сделать

Comment: О, я понял ваш ход мыслей. Большое спасибо. Я то думал к моему серверному скрипту могут выполнятся одновременно несколько запросов от пользователей, а оказывается только от одно. Спасибо. А если это чат, которые ищет людей по интересам и соеденяет их в чат, что лучше делать каждому сокет-соеденению свой поток?

Comment: Cмотря что такое поток с точки зрения питона. там какие то свои "легкие" потоки могут быть. С точки зрения операционной системы поток - это довольно тяжеловесная структура, легче чем отдельный процесс, но все таки. пока вам мощности одного ядра достаточно что бы обрабатывать коннекты, (которые 99% времени просто ждут данные), то потоки особо не нужны. Потоки понадобяться если какой то код работает скажем секунду не переставая, а остальные коннекты в это время ждут. Для чата я не могу пока придумать такого долгого кода